# How to remove the fieldsets that are pup around "list (text)" fields that have their display set to "Check Boxes / Radio Button"?

Tags: entities

We have a Drupal 9 website and are using "list (text)" fields whose displays are set to "Check Boxes/ Radio Button". This causes the output to be wrapped in a field set which we need to remove.

I have tried some trial and error (guessing) at altering the field in hook_form_alter() but the fieldset remains.

[image]
The field variable is below:

```
Array
(
    [#type] => container
    [#parents] => Array
        (
            [0] => field_order_item_logo_wrapper
        )

    [#attributes] => Array
        (
            [class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field--type-list-string
                    [1] => field--name-field-order-item-logo
                    [2] => field--widget-options-buttons
                )

        )

    [widget] => Array
        (
            [#title] => Image / Logo
            [#description] => 
            [#field_parents] => Array
                (
                )

            [#required] => 1
            [#delta] => 0
            [#weight] => 0
            [#element_validate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsButtonsWidget
                            [1] => validateElement
                        )

                )

            [#key_column] => value
            [#type] => radios
            [#default_value] => custom_logo
            [#options] => Array
                (
                    [custom_logo] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                            [string:protected] => Provide Logo
                        )

                    [stock_art_as_shown] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                            [string:protected] => Stock Art As Shown
                        )

                    [stock_logo] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                            [string:protected] => Stock Logo
                        )

                    [no_logo] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                            [string:protected] => No Logo
                        )

                    [logo_on_file] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                            [string:protected] => Logo is on File
                        )

                    [repeat] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                            [string:protected] => Repeat Exact Style as Previous Order
                        )

                )

            [#after_build] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsButtonsWidget
                            [1] => afterBuild
                        )

                )

            [#field_name] => field_order_item_logo
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_order_item_logo
                )

            [#tree] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: The screenshot shows an *Order Type* fieldset with the *New Order* and *Repeat Order* radio-buttons. What shown as field value contains a container (not a fieldset) and the *Provide Logo*, *Stock Art As Shown*, *Stock Logo*, **, *No Logo*, *Logo is on File*, and *Repeat Exact Style as Previous Order* radio-buttons. It seems the screenshot is for an entity field, but the field value is for another entity field.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to replicate with same settings as you have mentioned but for me its not adding field set please check it might be your theme settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for test and providing the screenshots. This is interesting then, I can't figure out where these fieldsets are being inserted for the radio/checks display. I'll dig in deeper.